# Append new key value pair on Click in the existing mock data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

Hi I am working on a task where I need to change the value of the boolean first and next I need to append the new key value pair on click. I have tried to use . operator to append the new key value pair but it's resulting in the error. My mock data is arrasy of object I need to add new key value pair(isDev:false) after the isProcessing:true Could any one help me what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

```
Mock Structure:

const mockItems = [
  {
    id: "1",
    itemType: "metal",
    doneBy: {
      id: "1",
      display: "Item Name"
    },
    catg: "A",
    createdDate: "01/01/2021",
    updatedBy: {
      id: "1",
      type: "M-A"
    },
    isProcessing: "true",
    subItems: [
      {
        id: "1",
        doneBy: {
          id: "1",
          display: "sub item name"
        },
        status: {
          type: "notapproved"
        },
        isProcessing: "true"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Code:

```
const [processingItem, setProcessingItem] = useState(mockItems);

const onClick = () => {
  setProcessingItem((prevState) => prevState.map((data) => (
  { ...data, isProcessing:false, data.isCreated=false})))
}
```

When I am adding the third argument my code is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the object key pairs use `key: value` assigning format.

```
const [processingItem, setProcessingItem] = useState(mockItems);

const onClick = () => {
  setProcessingItem((prevState) => prevState.map((data) => (
  { ...data, isProcessing:false, isCreated: false})))
}
```

Comment: it worked thanks a lot! is it possible to append only for the two items in the list ? I have tried using index  like  setProcessingItem((prevState) => prevState.map((data, i) => (i === 0 &&  i === 2 ?
  { ...data, isProcessing:false, isCreated: false}: data))) but it's not working
}